# Android action = USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED

Tags: java, android, android-studio, usb

Currently I have an activity in the application in which I work with a usb but once I connect the usb the application automatically starts that activity. I do not want that.

Is it possible to use USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED and prevent activity from starting when I connect USB?

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".Activity1"> </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Activity2"> </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Activity3">

    <intent-filter>

    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>

    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter"/>

    </activity>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove device-filter xml from manifest to get rid of autostart. You can still connect in started app without that xml.